# Firefox C++ Source Code help for detecting end of page content download

Tags: c++, firefox

I need to detect when a web page along with all its contents and embedded URLs, Images, Audio, Video etc. are completely downloaded. I debugged the file docshell/base/nsDocShell.cpp --> nsDocShell::LoadURI(). It gives me clear indication that page load is complete, but only problem is that I can still see page download in progress while above API indicated page download is over. Can someone help regarding this, Am I looking/digging into wrong location? I don't have to write AddOn or Extension, but only dig into base source code and take the information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no singular "all downloaded" state. After "everything" is downloaded, parsers might be still active, causing more downloads as more image tags and script tags are parsed, and so on. Parser might be paused even, e.g. when encountering synchronous script tags which.

The nearest "all complete" state is likely when [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState) is set to `"complete"` and the `load`/`error` event for the document is dispatched.
This happens (IIRC) in [`nsDocumentViewer::LoadComplete`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/base/nsDocumentViewer.cpp#964).

Even then more external resources might be loaded as a result of scripts inserting new tags, CSS rules being triggered, XMLHttpRequests and so on. Modern web sites are for that reason never fully loaded.

Comment: But, nsDocumentViewer::LoadComplete() is called even when no any URL is supplied to load, i.e. called along with browser itself even for blank page. Can you tell me how to ensure that page load end can be detected only for given URL.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the code, but each viewer has an associated document, which in turn has an associated uri/location. Skimming the code something like `mDocument && uri = mDocument->GetDocumentURI()` and comparing `uri` (nsIURI) should enable you to compare URIs and run further code only when the uri matches something.